# Seeding a Pivot Table in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

How should I effectively seed a pivot table regarding the fact that when in the seeder class PostTagTableSeeder it asks to set the path of the table's model

TestDummy::times(10)->create('App\Model');

but as pivot tables don't have models I dont know what to fill.

should I use the table's name? like

TestDummy::times(10)->create('post_tag');

Comment: Are you using laravel 5 or 5.1?

Comment: @RossWilson Im using laravel 5 yet, until there is more info in laravel 5.1

Comment: Laravel 5.1 was released about 2 months ago. There are only a few differences between 5 and 5 (IMO) - the directory structure, and then there are a few pretty cool features that have been included. One of the features included is Model Factories which makes this process a breeze. I haven't used TestDummy but after a quick look around it requires a modified version of Testdummy (however, I could be mistaken).

Comment: Thanks @RossWilson, I have seen some lessons of laravel 5 in laracasts.com recently published, so Im thinking that Laravel 5 is still working. So I will try to look up for a solution in this version, if I can't find it I will check Laravel 5.1, thank you for the advice.